# How to generate 2 different shared libraries using the same MakeFile

Tags: c++, makefile

I have a set of sub projects which are linked each other. Each sub project generate shared libraries (.so files) using MakeFiles, for a reason for a one sub project I need to generate same shared library file in 2 different names using the MakeFile. I have specify original make target as below

```
target         = pr-libOne
target_version = 1.2
target_libs    = pr-libx pr-liby
```

In this case I will get `pr-libone.so.1.2.0` and `pr-libone.so` files. Now I need to generate same shared library in a different name using the same MakeFile (say other name is pr-libtwo). Is this able to do with MakeFile ?

Comment: Is it enough just to copy the result of the 1st build? Then just add another target rule with the copy action.

Comment: Yes, Just copy the library with different name also OK